# Detecting user browser with PHP and displaying notice accordingly

Tags: php, browser

What is the most efficient way to detect the user's browser using PHP? I need a function to block users with IE from accessing my website pages and pop them a link towards Chrome, Ff and Safari (they will choose which one they wish to download...). (Reason: I'm using various jquery functions and some scripts that don't work/show up properly on IE and I want my visitors to have the optimal experience).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` can help

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this code to add css according to the browsers as the same css wont work for ff and chrome...This might help you.

```
<?php
$b = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(strstr(strtolower($b),"msie"))
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css">';
else if(strstr(strtolower($b),"firefox"))
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ff.css">';
else if(strstr(strtolower($b),"chrome"))
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cr.css">';
?>
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 2):

On the server side, all you can do is look at the HTTP User-Agent header. Have a look at the [`get_browser`](http://php.net/manual/function.get-browser.php) function, which parses this for you. This is voluntary information though and not guaranteed to be accurate.

Comment: `get_browser` is not method, it's a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_browser`](http://php.net/function.get-browser) function and [browscap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/stream.asp?BrowsCapINI) file that is maintained by Browser [Capabilities Project](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp).